# Applying the residue theorem on a real integral

Tags: complex-numbers, residue-calculus

$$\int\frac{d\theta}{a + b\cos\theta}$$

Given that

$$\cos\theta = \frac{z  + z^{-1}}{2}$$
$$d\theta = \frac{dz}{iz}$$

We have

$$\oint_c \frac{dz}{iz\left(a + b\frac{z +z^{-1}}{2}\right)}$$

$$\oint_c \frac{dz}{ibz^2 + 2iaz + ib}$$

Now my guess is to obtain the roots of $z$.

How do I choose the pole to be substituted in the residue theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1}{iz(a + b\frac{z +z^{-1}}{2})}=-2i \frac{1}{ bz^2+2az+b}$$

The poles are given by solving
$$bz^2+2az+b=0$$

Comment: Where did $i$ go?

Comment: @paranoidhominid $$\frac{1}{i}=-i$$ It jumped in front of the fraction ;)